# How to expose Gitlab Package Registry without access token?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

For access to gitlabs `Package Registry`, it requires the use of an `access_token`, like a private-token that is added to `maven` `settings.xml`. Otherwise the registry is not accessible.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Question: how can I expose the libraries inside the registry without authentication? Or better to say: every user in the company that has access to gitlab should be able to simply fetch the libraries without having to add any tokens to their maven configuration.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: If your company uses Maven, it probably runs a Nexus or Artifactory server. This would be the right place to define the above repository and make it available to everyone.

Comment: No I don't, and I simply want to make 2-3 common libraries available in my gitlab, plus allow others to resolve and work with them without any access tokens.

Comment: If you have more than five people using Maven, you should run your own Nexus/Artifactory. This solves a lot of problems you otherwise have.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to access the package registry in Gitlab (nor in Github) without an access token... which is one of the reasons I recommend as repository manager as well (already mentioned in another post)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New answer**

Since GitLab 15.7, ou can follow the section [Allow anyone to pull from package registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/#allow-anyone-to-pull-from-package-registry) in the documentation:

> To allow anyone to pull from the package registry, regardless of project visibility:
>
> 1. On the left sidebar, select Search or go to and find your private or internal project.
> 2. Select Settings > General.
> 3. Expand Visibility, project features, permissions.
> 4. Turn on the Allow anyone to pull from Package Registry toggle.
>    Select Save changes.
>
> Anyone on the internet can access the package registry for the project.

**Old answer**

There is an [open proposal](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/329253) to:

> Add feature-specific controls for the GitLab Package and Registry, so that Admin have more flexibility and control in how they can share their project's resources.

but this is not yet implemented.

The package registry visibility permissions is then derived from the project visibility as defined in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/).

If you want to give access to the package registry without authentication, the only solution, for now, seems to have a public project with package registry enabled.